# su vs system-app ( for shutdown / reboot -p )

Tags: android, root, su

I want to shutdown one android device via code. I can do so with

```
su reboot -p
```

But now I want to do this with my app that is signed with the system key without the need for rooting the device - but strangely I get:

```
reboot: Operation not permitted
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction

Comment: What is the *full* log that results?  Are your attempting to exec the reboot program, or are you calling an internal API?  Do you have any associated permissions in your manifest?   The platform keys governs their granting, but you still have to request them.

Comment: Hi, Have you found the solution since 7 years ? :)

Comment: no :-( but tbh I also do not remember for what project I needed that at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a su command. Use Android's native methods. `PowerManager` has a method `reboot()` as documented here: [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Full code example [here](http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:reboot_android_device_programmatically_from_an_app:txt)

Hope this helps

Comment: I do not want to reboot - I want to shutdown - this is not possible with this API